# Detect if Desktop View is selected in Mobile/Tab/IPad

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to detect in Javascript that User has selected Desktop View in devices  for my site?
I want to  show a message  to user.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two options. First is here [StackOverflowLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device). If the first not suits you I can recommend this one [device-detector-js library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/device-detector-js)